# Use lambdas to get polymorphism, recursion, and true OO style in CUDA?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, cuda

I'm trying to migrate a big C++11 library to CUDA. The library builds a hierarchical tree of "Nodes", sharing the same virtual interface but implementing different algorithms, and then calculates the value of the root node for a number of trials. In each trial, the library changes some setting in the leaf nodes of the hierarchy, and then proceeds to recursively recalculate all node values upwards towards the root.

The library has the trial change on the outermost loop, and heavily uses polymorphic virtual classes. It is not feasible to redesign this aspect of it. What I could redesign are the value calculation functions, in order to vectorize them and make them run in kernel space.

Here's a cut down of the original, serial library:

```
// virtual ancestor
class Node {
public:
    // Return value of this node for the current trial.
    // This method will recursively call the value() method
    // of the direct children of this Node.
    virtual float value() = 0;
};

// Implement y = a1*x1 + a2*x2 + ... + an*xn,
// where x* are the values  of the direct children of this node
// and a* are constants
class LinearCombination: virtual public Node {
public:
    // skip: constructor

    float value() {
        float acc = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            // Recursively get value of child
            acc += children[i]->value() * weights[i];
        }
        return acc;
    }

protected:
    std::vector<Node *> children;
    std::vector<float> weights;
};


int main() {
    Node * root;
    // skip: initialise tree of nodes
    for (auto trial: trials) {
        // skip: setup global trial settings. This will change
        // the result of the leaf Nodes.
        auto value = root->value();
        // skip: dump to disk
    }
}
```

My first conversion attempt changes the value() method to calculate the value of each node in a vectorized way, that is for all trials at once. All flow control remains in plain C++, and only the actual maths is moved to the graphics card.
This is necessary because virtual polymorphism doesn't work inside a kernel, and it's very difficult to implement tree data structures (Node ** children can't be used).

```
class Node {
public:
    // Return value for all scenarios
    // result is a buffer in the device memory
    virtual void value(float * result, int n) = 0;
};

class LinearCombination: virtual public Node {
public:
    // skip: constructor

    void value(float * result, int n) {
        hemi::parallel_for(0, n, [=] HEMI_LAMBDA (int i) {
            result[i] = 0.0;
        });

        // Allocate temporary buffer to store the value of the underlyings
        float * scratch;
        cudaMalloc((void **)&scratch, n * sizeof(float));

        for (size_t child_id = 0; child_id < children.size(); child_id++) {
            // Recursively get value of child
            children[child_id]->value(scratch, n);
            auto weight = weights[child_id];

            hemi::parallel_for(0, n, [=] HEMI_LAMBDA (int i) {
                result[i] += scratch[i] * weight;
            });
        }

        cudaFree(scratch);
    }

protected:
    std::vector<Node *> children;
    std::vector<float> weights;
};


int main() {
    Node * root;
    // skip: allocate nodes

    // Create buffer for output value of the root nodes
    float * value;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&value, n * sizeof(float));

    // skip: initialise vectors of data for the leaf nodes
    root->value(value, n);
    // skip: dump to disk
    cudaFree(value);
}
```

The above technically works, but its performance is poor - on a GeForce GTX 970, running on 500,000 trials in parallel, it goes only 10x as fast as the serial algorithm goes on a single CPU - put it on a 16-core computer, and the GPU is slower.

This is unsurprising, as in the linear combination example above the value() function performs 3n+1 memory accesses (where n is the number of children), which could be completely avoided if the whole computation were done inside a single kernel.

So I came up with the idea of using the new C++11 Lambda support in CUDA 7.5:

```
class Node {
public:
    // Return __device__ lambda which returns the value
    // of the node for a single trial
    virtual std::function<float (int)> valueFunc() = 0;
};


class LinearCombination: virtual public Node {
public:
    // skip: constructor

    std::function<float (int)> valueFunc() {
        auto func = [=] HEMI_LAMBDA (int i) {
            return 0.0;
        };

        for (size_t child_id = 0; child_id < children.size(); child_id++) {
            auto childFunc = children[child_id]->valueFunc();
            auto weight = weights[child_id];

            func = [=] HEMI_LAMBDA (int i) {
                return func(i) + childFunc(i) * weight;
            };
        }
        return func;
    }

protected:
    std::vector<Node *> children;
    std::vector<float> weights;
};


int main() {
    Node * root;
    // skip: allocate nodes

    // Create buffer for output value of the root node
    float * scratch;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&scratch, n * sizeof(float));

    // skip: initialise vectors of data for the leaf nodes
    auto valueFunc = root->valueFunc();
    hemi::parallel_for(0, n, [=] HEMI_LAMBDA (int i) {
        scratch[i] = valueFunc(i);
    });

    // skip: dump to disk
    cudaFree(scratch);
}
```

The idea of the above is that there is one big kernel that processes the whole tree, assembled at runtime as a recursion of scalar lambdas, so the whole tree calculation performs ONE memory write, plus whatever input vector the leaf nodes need to read.

However, it doesn't compile, and I can't understand if it's just a matter of syntax or if what I'm trying to do is outright impossible.

If the above can't be fixed, are there any alternative solutions to the problem? As mentioned earlier, refactoring the whole library to be less recursive, less object-oriented, or less based on virtual polymorphism is not an option.

Comment: `std::function` is not lamnda.

Comment: please help me understand how I can have a function that returns a__device__ lambda then

Comment: CUDA C++ supports polymorphism, so I for one don't understand this comment: "virtual polymorphism doesn't work inside a kernel,"  It's true that objects *created on the host* can't be used polymorphically on the device, but this is fairly easy to address, in my opinion, simply by instantiating the objects on the device, rather than the host.  Or perhaps I don't know what you mean by "virtual polymorphism"

Comment: I mean having objects which, as an attribute, have arrays of pointers to other objects with common interface but different implementation. See my example above where the LinearCombination class needs to iterate on an array of children Node pointers, without knowing how each of them actually implements the value() method, and without knowing in advance how many children there's going to be.

Comment: You might consider just stripping this question down to a simple compilation question and include a standalone repro that people can try out, as well as the compilation errors and nvcc version number.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, CUDA does support virtual function calls, as well as call through a function pointer. You just need to take a pointer to `__device__` function on the device, not on the host.

That being said, be aware that actual function calls on the device are very expensive. That is because you need to keep a call stack for thousands of threads at the same time. Keeping theads in sync is another potential challenge.
Typical CUDA programs actually inline all calls to produce a single block of code.

I don't know the details of your program, so I can only guess what you need.
How about trying the following approach:

- Copy all the plain node data on the device, but keep all virtuality and actual graph structure on the host.
- Walk the graph structure on the CPU, but instead of performing the calculation, *record* what needs to be computed
- Idenitify each virtual function by a unique index. There is a finite number of them, right? (by finite - I mean, a manageable number)
- Create a planar work queue. Each element would hold the node index and the function index you need to compute. If you can, reorder the queue so that neighbouring threads would perform the same thing.
- Transfer the queue to device. Run code with a big switch statement that selects the correct function depending on its index.

Yes, it seems a bit crude, but it can help you avoid a major overhead. When using CUDA with nonhomogeneous data (e.g. graphs) the hard part is usually how to organize and schedule your work, and not just how to actually compute what you need.

Comment: Keeping a map of all device functions in a single kernel is not really doable as the size of the library grows. Is it possible to copy to device memory an array of \_\_device\_\_ function pointers instead? If so, how?